# Using variables for region names in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, javascript-objects

I'm building an application that makes heavy use of Marionette's Layouts and regions. However, I want to be able to pass a variable as a region when rendering, like this.

```
var x = "main_region";
someLayout.x.show(new SomeView());
```

However, I keep getting an error like so:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'someLayout.x.show')
```

This may just be a pure Javascript error, or a backbone one, or a Marionette one. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somelayout[x].show( ... ) is the syntax you are looking for.  In JS, all members can be accessed using . or [] notation.  The former is easier to read and for tools to optimize but the latter supports variables.

Comment: Thanks! I always get confused with the difference between square bracket and dot. You're awesome!